# Grouping array and sort it

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have array and want to grouping array with _level and _parent and then _id will sorted so the output will displaying:

```
array(
   '163' => array (
               "desc" => "master array",
               "_id" => 163,
               "_parent" => null,
               "_level" => 1,
           ),     
   '172' => array (
               "desc" => "sub array",
               "_id" => 172,
               "_parent" => 163,
               "_level" => 2,
            ),
    '167' => array (
               "desc" => "sub array from 172",
                "_id" => 167,
                "_parent" => 172,
                "_level" => 3,
             ),         
     '200' => array (
                "desc" => "sub array",
                "_id" => 200,
                "_parent" => 163,
                "_level" => 2,
             ),    
      '165' => array (
                "desc" => "sub array from 200",
                "_id" => 165,
                "_parent" => 200,
                "_level" => 3,
             ),
      );
```

How to possible to get this output, I tried with usort and create group of array but still not get my expecting output.

Comment: can you please post your expected output?

Comment: on blockquote section is my expecting output

Comment: Not like that its confusing, post the array you are expecting as an output.

Comment: ok i post only my expected an output

Comment: What was the original array? Without it how can we solve your problem?

Comment: the original array is a random of my expecting output, sorry i can't post my original array because validation SO forbids me to post too much code

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$myArray = array(
'163' => array (
           "desc" => "master array",
           "_id" => 163,
           "_parent" => null,
           "_level" => 1,
       ),      
'172' => array (
           "desc" => "sub array",
           "_id" => 172,
           "_parent" => 163,
           "_level" => 2,
        ),
'167' => array (
           "desc" => "sub array from 172",
            "_id" => 167,
            "_parent" => 172,
            "_level" => 3,
         ),         
 '200' => array (
            "desc" => "sub array",
            "_id" => 200,
            "_parent" => 163,
            "_level" => 2,
         ),     
  '165' => array (
            "desc" => "sub array from 200",
            "_id" => 165,
            "_parent" => 200,
            "_level" => 3,
         ),
  );

usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
return ($a['_level'] <=> $b['_id']);
 });

foreach($myArray as $array)
echo $array['desc']."<br>";
```

Output:

> master array
>   sub array
>   sub array from 172
>   sub array
>   sub array from 200

Comment: what is the expected output? You wanted to sort it through values?

Comment: master array, sub array 172, sub array from 172, sub array 200, sub array from 200, please check my edited question

Comment: check the edit and reference from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value